# How to add bundler to gemset with rvm (single user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

There is error in Capistrano rails 3.1.3 deployment saying:

```
    [176.195.225.93] executing command
 ** [out :: 176.195.225.93] ←[31mERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.←[m←(B
```

However `gem list` shows bundler 1.0.22. Our server is running rvm. It seems that the bundler was not added to the ruby gemset. Is there a way to add bundler to ruby gemset so the rvm will find bundler?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your path is not getting set, meaning that bundle cannot be found. You should be able to do something like this...

```
set :default_environment, {
'PATH' => "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/<ruby-dir>/bin",
'GEM_HOME' => '<ruby-dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.8',
'GEM_PATH' => '<ruby-dir>lib/ruby/gems/1.8',
'BUNDLE_PATH' => '<ruby-dir>/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems'  
}
```

as per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541721/capistrano-bundle-not-found-error-during-deployment)

Alternatively, it is possible to configure your server to execute a profile when executing remote commands via ssh as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)